# Spark serialization (?) with traits weirdness and discrepancies between 1.6.0 ang 2.1.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

I know there are lots of questions about this, but I wasn't able to find a systematic explanation of what exactly needs to be serializable (and when it is serialized) ... and of how this requirement is verified.

Consider this:

```
class Baz
trait Bar { val baz = new Baz; def bar(i: Int) = baz }
case object Foo extends Bar { def foo = sc.parallelize(1 to 1).map(bar).collect }
Foo.foo
```

This works, and returns `Array(null)`
Does it make sense to anyone???

If I change `val` to `lazy val`, than it *stops working*, and throws `NotSerializableException`, which makes sense - it initializes `baz` on the remote side, and then fails to send it back. 
But why does it happily replace it with `null` in the first case???

If I write it, pretty much, any other way I can think of - move `bar` definition from trait to object for example, or replace `bar` call with `_ => baz` - it also stops working, and complains that `Task is not serializable`.

What is it with a method returning a val that is defined in a trait, that makes it just write it as a `null` instead? Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
The above behavior happens on scala 2.11 with spark 2.1.1. 
Scala 2.10 (spark 1.6.0) does throw an exception, complaining that `Baz` isn't serializable ... So, this seems to be a regression.

*Also* I noticed that on spark 1.6.0, something like this works fine:

```
   object Foo { def foo = sc.parallelize(1 to 1).map(bar).collect; def bar(i: Int) = i+1 } 
   Foo.foo
```

But on spark 2.1.1 it complains that `Foo` isn't serializable. Why is that? 
Apparently, serializing lambda wants to also serialize `Foo`, which *sort of* makes sense ... except that it *does* work in 1.6.0 somehow, even if I make labda actually reference other things in `Foo`:

```
   object Foo { 
     var stuff = 10 
     def foo = sc.parallelize(1 to 1).map(bar).collect
     def bar(i: Int) = { stuff += 1; i+1 }
   } 
   Foo.foo
   Foo.stuff
```

This works fine in 1.6.0, but not in 2.1.1.

So, one question here is how does it actually work in 1.6.0? I mean, `Foo` isn't serializable, how does it know the value of `stuff` on the other end?

The other, obvious, question is - why did it stop working in 2.1.1? Are there subtle problems with 1.6.0 behavior, should we not be relying on it?
Or is it just a bug in 2.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

That might not be a straight answer in a sense that would give you the exact reasoning behind the serialization issues in Spark and why your use case would possibly be working this way or another, but...let me shed some light on this.

`SparkContext` is where it all happens (or at least where it is started). Among the methods you can find [clean](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2289-L2292) method:

```
private[spark] def clean[F <: AnyRef](f: F, checkSerializable: Boolean = true): F = {
  ClosureCleaner.clean(f, checkSerializable)
  f
}
```

Quoting its scaladoc you should be given enough information about how Spark does the serialization validation:

> Clean a closure to make it ready to serialized and send to tasks (removes unreferenced variables in $outer's, updates REPL variables)
>
> If `checkSerializable` is set, `clean` will also proactively check to see if `f` is serializable and throw a `SparkException` if not.

Searching for all the places where the method is used may throw some light on why your code may or may not work. It's just as simple as applying `clean` method to your code.

You may also start with [RDD.map](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L369) operator where you find the `clean` method:

```
val cleanF = sc.clean(f)
```

With that you may build some understanding of why your code can give different results per whether you use `val` or `lazy val`.

I think that in the end your code could be rewritten as follows:

```
// run spark-shell -c spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts=true
// use :paste -raw
package org.apache.spark

class Baz
trait Bar { lazy val baz = new Baz; def bar(i: Int) = baz }
case object Foo extends Bar {
  val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "Clean", new SparkConf)
  def foo = sc.clean(bar _)
}

// org.apache.spark.Foo.foo
```

I used `spark-shell` for this and it appears that the code worked fine with and without `lazy` keyword in Spark **2.3.0-SNAPSHOT** built today.

Comment: Actually, the only thing I _do_ understand about all this badness, is the difference in the results between `val` and `lazy val` case :) 
Everything else seems like a big pile of ... mystery :)

Comment: Also, forgot to mention: the code you wrote does work the same way with and without `lazy`, but it's not doing the same thing I had in my (first) snippet. If you change `foo` to be `sc.parallelize(1 to 1).map(sc.clean(bar)).collect`, then it will throw with lazy (which is understandable), but "work", and return an array with _null_ without lazy, which just does not make any sense.